# Google Compute Engine: execute a shell command inside vm directly from gcloud console

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to automate creation of VMs in GCE.
I want to ssh into my VM and execute a command directly through the gcloud console.
`> gcloud compute ssh <instance>` will open a new ssh window, instead of that, I want to execute the shell command inside VM directly from gcloud console without redirecting to a new ssh window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `--command` flag for that:

```
gcloud compute ssh <instance> --command <command>
```